# Criterios muy dispares en votación de respuestas

Tags: discusión, cierre-de-preguntas, votos, comentarios, eliminación-de-respuestas

En esta pregunta quiero poner tres ejemplos que he conseguido rápidamente de los últimos días que espero ilustren lo que me parece una falta de criterio grave que conlleva un desincentivo a la hora de crear publicaciones de calidad en este sitio y, por tanto, a una reducción de la calidad en general. No pretendo hacer una crítica personal de nadie, simplemente son ejemplos de lo que quiero hablar y comportamientos que rechazo como miembro de esta comunidad.

#### 1.- Ejemplo de respuesta que no mejora en absoluto la de otro compañero

Antes de contestar se deberían leer todas las respuestas actuales y, en caso de que se pueda mejorar, añadir un comentario con la mejora propuesta. Si esa mejora es clara y no se tiene una contestación de ningún tipo, entiendo que se pueda crear otra añadiendo la mejora aunque sea días después.
[Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54459/19623) no tiene ninguna mejora. Hice al autor un comentario al respecto, en aquel momento tenía un voto positivo ya que no entendía, y en el momento de publicar este "meta" ya tiene dos: alguien que ya sabe que es una respuesta que no aporta nada ha dado otro voto positivo. **No puede entenderlo sinceramente**

#### 2.- Ejemplo de respuesta que se encuentra MUY fácilmente en Google

La pregunta ¿Qué diferencia hay entre int e Integer? no aporta nada nuevo al sitio. Si se introduce tal cual esta hecha en SOes aparecen 209.000 resultados, también en español, que resuelven la duda. El OP no ha puesto nada de lo que ha intentado, ha declarado que es para un trabajo de clase y su pregunta exacta era acerca de la diferencia entre `int[]` e `Integer[]`. [Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54420/19623) ha recibido (hasta el momento) 6 votos (6ª más votada de la semana y 2ª de los útimos dos días), no añade nada nuevo que no ponga en la búsqueda de Google, no es "académicamente " correcta ya que lo primero que dice es que hay que diferenciar entre "tipo primitivo" y "objeto" lo cuál es formalmente incorrecto (más en el caso que `int[]` e `Integer[]` sí que son objetos porque los dos son arreglos y es lo que pide el OP). Incluso el comentario a la pregunta de @sstan es más útil para la pregunta específica del OP y sólo tiene un voto positivo.

#### 3.- Ejemplo de respuesta de calidad (lo que se supone que queremos)

[Esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54090/19623) es el tipo de respuestas que queremos. Se pueden apreciar muchos aspectos de la potencia de la POO, su solución es actual, advierte de ello por si acaso, es completa, eficaz, etc... parece que lo único malo es que se hizo un día mas tarde que el resto. El total de sus votos es 1, el mío, nadie más parece valorar esa respuesta. Este usuario que parece que dejo SOes durante unos meses y ahora ha vuelto, ha respondido una pregunta y ve que nadie valora su esfuerzo creo que no recibe el feedback merecido.

#### Conclusión

El primer caso me parece una falta de respeto por el trabajo de otros compañeros, un comportamiento típico de alguien que sólo mira su ombligo (o en este caso sus puntos de reputación) y sin interés por de verdad querer aportar algo mejor al sitio, sólo el ruido causado por tener más publicaciones repetidas. **Creo que esas publicaciones deben tratarse como de baja calidad y ser eliminadas, sobre todo cuando han pasado días entre entre ambas respuestas**

El segundo caso la pregunta es la que debía haber sido cerrada directamente al tratarse de un trabajo académico en el que no se ha añadido ningún resumen del esfuerzo realizado para solucionarlo (con la facilidad de la pregunta es cero). Al ser tan "fácil" de responder (las comillas las pongo porque en realidad nadie ha contestado correcta y completamente a la pregunta específica), los cazadores de puntos responderán rápidamente a esas preguntas sin molestarse en mover un dedo en enseñar al OP que su comportamiento no es adecuado, que deben leerse las normas (el OP no tienen ni la medalla *informado*) y que de lo contrario su pregunta será cerrada por falta de esfuerzo.

El tercer caso producirá que los usuarios que pueden dar calidad al sitio se desalienten ante estas injusticias y falta de observación de las normas que nos hemos dado para la integridad del sitio.

#### ¿Qué hacer?

=> *QUÉ ESPERO CONSEGUIR*

1. Informar a los OPs que hacen preguntas sin cumplir las normas (normalmente preguntas que demuestran una falta de esfuerzo), emitir votos de cierre e informar a los que realicen respuestas a estas preguntas de que su comportamiento no es adecuado.
   => *SE EVITAN PUBLICACIONES NO DESEADAS*
2. Antes de publicar nada (incluso un comentario) leer todas las publicaciones actuales en toda la pregunta y actualizar la página en caso de que se nos avise que ha habido una edición. Sólo después de esto obrar en consecuencia.
   => *SE MUESTRA RESPETO POR EL TRABAJO DE LOS COMPAÑEROS*
3. Otorgar votos positivos sólo a respuestas sobre preguntas correctas que las resuelvan completamente y sin errores o informar por comentarios si hay alguna mejora para que el autor pueda reaccionar.
   => *SE AUMENTA EL NIVEL DE CALIDAD DE LAS RESPUESTAS QUE QUEDARÁN PARA EL RESTO DE USUARIOS PARA LA POSTERIDAD*
4. Si entramos una vez al día, revisar las publicaciones activas del último día para centrarnos en las que son de calidad independientemente de la hora a la que se redactaron y, sobretodo a lo que son nuevas preguntas o respuestas y que sean de las etiquetas sobre las que tenemos más conocimiento.
   => *SE INCENTIVAN LAS APORTACIONES DE OTROS MIEMBROS EN USOS HORARIOS MENOS POPULARES O CON MENOS TIEMPO DISPONIBLE PARA COLABORAR*

¿Qué os parecen estas medidas y cuál es el grado de apoyo que estais dispuestos a realizar?

Comment: en desacuerdo, intentar controlar estas cosas es imposible y ademas no es escalable a medida que crece la comunidad xq cada perona (y generacion) tiene sus propios codigos. Ya tenemos herramientas, votos, banderas, etc.

Comment: No comparto tu enfoque del punto 2: si tiene tantos resultados en Google, será porque es algo que la gente considera importante comunicar. Existen varias aproximaciones: si la pregunta está mal formulada, la cerramos; si ya se preguntó, se marca como duplicada. Pero si no es ninguno de estos dos casos, es pertinente en este sitio y contribuye a generar contenido para el sitio. Esto en cuanto a la pregunta. En cuanto a la respuesta, creo que "no aporta nada que no dé Google" no es argumento válido por lo dicho antes. Además, si tiene errores, ¡coméntaselos! Así mejoraremos el sitio.

Comment: @fedorqui la popularidad de un tema no lo hace apropiado. Justin Bieber tiene más resultados pero no es un problema de programación. Esa pregunta tampoco es un problema de programación, la respuesta está al alcance del mínimo esfuerzo. Algo más que esto último es lo que tienen que demostrar las preguntas para trabajos académicos según las normas. No es un "enfoque" particular, es algo claro. Lo que se debate es si se les va a hacer caso o no, y este último caso, si se va a informar a los más inexpertos de las normas que tenemos o se va a fomentar el evitarlas por no discutir o ganar puntos.

Comment: Evidentemente estamos hablando de programación, no de música (o pseudomúsica jeje). Consultar la _diferencia entre declarar int [] vector o declarar Integer [] vector_ no es malo _per se_. Lo malo es no mostrar esfuerzo por su parte, pero la pregunta es de programación y está en el ámbito del sitio de acuerdo con el [tour]. Por otra parte, está en tu mano hacer todo esto que sugieres: comenta al OP, sugiere mejoras o vota para cerrarla. En muchos casos, los comentarios hacen mejorar mucho la forma de expresar una pregunta por parte de los nuevos usuarios.

Comment: @EmanuelVe tu idea es que como "no se puede solucionar" no hacer nada? Ya tenemos herramientas? Si tengo un martillo de carpintero y uso la parte picuda para clavar y la roma para sacar un clavo, quizás siendo muy bruto consiga lo primero después de doblar alguno y no conseguiré lo segundo nunca. Yo propongo una forma de utilizar las herramientas que dices para conseguir lo que pongo porque creo que se ajusta a las normas y me parece más justo. Si estás en desacuerdo podrías responder con otra propuesta para valorarla, pero si se puede arreglar dejame intentarlo antes de decir que es imposible

Comment: @fedorqui claro que la pregunta es de programación, pero no de mínimo esfuerzo. Con lo mínimo nunca hubiera llegado a hacerse. Igual que preguntas duplicadas que salen al principio de búsquedas pero se repiten aquí. Yo he aprendido Java por mi cuenta. Siempre que tengo un problema busco en Internet y todavía no he tenido que hacer ninguna pregunta nunca. No pido eso (porque suelo ir a sitios ingleses), pero sí pido el mínimo esfuerzo, lo cual invalida la pregunta. Para colmo se ha aceptado una respuesta que no responde a la pregunta. Desde mi punto de vista es por el vago esfuerzo de nuevo.

Comment: Coincido en que la pregunta no muestra ningún esfuerzo,pero [es.so] nació para ofrecer ayuda en español a los programadores, de ahí que encontrar un recurso en inglés no es motivo para no preguntarlo aquí. Además, no es malo preguntar: contribuye a que más gente aprenda. La validez de una respuesta no determina si una pregunta es buena o no; la cantidad de esfuerzo del OP determina si se acepta en el momento o no, pero su éxito es algo que escapa de sus manos. Un ejemplo: una pregunta de [so] tiene 3 millones de visitas y más de 2000 votos; su copia en [pt.so] fue cerrada por demasiado amplia.

Comment: @fedorqui como no se qué pregunta es no puedo tener criterio para responderte al respecto. Si fuera una pregunta sobre un trabajo académico que no muestra ningún esfuerzo me da igual que SOen lo haga mal también. En sus normas al respecto pone lo mismo que en las nuestras con lo que no debía haber sido admitida. Voy a añadir otra respuesta a ver si es más aceptada. Básicamente va a ser: "No te tomes las normas en serio haz y deja hacer lo que pienses en cada momento porque si algo es popular es bueno". Si es más votado entonce pediré que se cambien las normas.

Answer (score 3):

Pues creo que muy dispares no son. Sobre todo la 2 y la 3.

Para bien o para mal, Stackoverflow en español aparece en los primeros lugares de las páginas de resultados cuando se buscan preguntas relacionadas con la temática del sitio. Es de suponer se encuentren fácilmente en Google.

Mira el segundo caso: si buscas "Diferencia entre int e Integer" en Google, la pregunta de SOes aparece en tercer lugar https://www.google.com.mx/search?&q=Diferencia+entre+int+e+Integer.

Y relacionado con el tercer punto: entre más contenido haya en SOes, entre más usuarios lo visiten, entre más gente haga clic en los resultados de las búsquedas en Google, el fenómeno que observas en el punto 2 se a repetir cada vez. Pero **ese es el resultado esperado**: *más visitantes* que se conviertan en *más usuarios* que creen *más contenido* (y ojalá fuera contenido de calidad).

Con respecto al punto 1. Pues si, sería genial que los que responden hicieran eso que dices. Y es muy loable lo que tu haces. Por otro lado, es mejor votar que no votar.

#### Conclusión

Estás peleando contra *molinos de viento* y yo te apoyo.

Answer (score 1):

Es como dice @toledano, la administración es flexible por que quiere jalar gente y les conviene (supongo que a todos) que mas personas participen pues da publicidad y el sitio crece.

Soy de la idea que en cuanto existan suficientes usuarios pasara lo mismo que en la versión en ingles, preguntas de mala calidad son cerradas o eliminadas en cuestión de minutos.

Hay que tener paciencia.

Answer (score -15):

Viendo (según el número de votos y los comentarios) que nadie comparte las medidas que he propuesto en la pregunta (más bien alguno como @EmanueleVe ha actuado deliberadamente en contra), voy a resumir en esta respuesta otra opción a tomar a la hora de usar las herramientas que tenemos:

#### Propuesta nueva

No hay que tomarse las normas en serio. Para que haya buen ambiente incluso con los usuarios que no aceptan críticas constructivas, haz y deja hacer lo que pienses en cada momento.
Si algo es popular es bueno. Esto ayudará a tener más enlaces en Google. Da igual si es lo primero que aprendes leyendo cualquier blog de un aficionado. Piensa que eso atraerá a más personas que realmente no tienen idea del tema. Si no se quieren esforzar como pone en las normas aquí podemos responder incluso a preguntas como la de este ejemplo:

#### Ejemplo de pregunta popular (contenido deseado)

**Q significa este código de ensamblado o algo asi?**

Hola hamijos, primero de todo decirles que no tengo ni idea de programar, pero en Instagram e bisto este código y no sé q hace. e sentido curiosidad i e pensado que podían ayudarme con mi problema.

EDITO: Añado el kodigo que no lo puse y me lo han pedido, creí que ya sabrían a qué me refería

`System.out.println("Hola Mundo!");`

1 hamijo me a dicho q si lo digo tres veces delante de un espejo, *Siri* se hará carne a mi lado y podré tener una conversación con ella ylo q surja. Aunque me daba mucho miedo provarlo me duché y prepare para la cita (aunque llevaba una compresa puesta por si acaso el miedo, ya saben) y pero no a funcionado ni con luz de velas. ¿Podrian decirme qué es lo q ago mal? Por favor ayudenme.Gracias. Es urgente por favor!!!!!!!!!!

En Goole había 16.500 resultados pero e pensado q aki podrían hecharme una mano como hicieron con otro hamijo que me conto que este sitio te acen el kodigo gratis si das votos a las respuestas y saben mucho.

Muchas gracias de nuevo son los mejores. Los quiero <3 XX.

Este tipo de preguntas harán que suba la popularidad del sitio, sobre todo si las comparten en sus redes sociales. Ya he visto cosas parecidas y se hacen virales así que ayudará a captar usuarios que taerán más contenido, tráfico, etc... y harán la comunidad más grande que es lo que queremos.

Se trata de una pregunta de programación, se ve que lo ha intentado y es para obtener un asistente virtual que también tiene que ver con la informática. Incluso manda besos así que es muy lindo y se merece que no lo critiquen.

Si algún usuario agresivo vota para cerrar este tipo de preguntas no le hagan caso. Lo que tienen que hacer es responder rápido que yo les votaré siempre a todas porque no me cuesta nada y como tampoco soy un experto cualquier cosa que pongan (incluso repetida) me parecerá bien.

Otra cosa, si ese usuario da argumentos en alguna pregunta sobre que una respuesta es mejor que otra vds voten por la que piensa que es peor, aunque se haya hecho un mes más tarde. Estén preparados para que les responda con otro comentario dando más razones y pidiéndoles algun tipo de explicación sobre su comportamiento o pidiéndoles que argumenten porque la respuesa que no le gusta es mejor. Cuando sea así simplemente deben decirle que la otra es mala y punto, no se molesten en dar explicaciones, mejor busquen otro usuario que de más votos a la pregunta repetida para que vea que son vds los que tienen razón porque los votos al azar es lo que importa.

Para esto último yo uso un dado y me va muy bien. Si no pueden rascar puntos de una pregunta porque está respondida no se molesten en entrar. Sólo entren en las recientes que no ha dado tiempo en responder y hagan una respuesta casi vacía sólo para "pillar sitio". Incluso pueden dar respuestas en otro lenguaje de programación para dar más ideas. En las otras preguntas que hace mucho tiempo que no están activas (2 horas por ejemplo uff) puede haber respuestas muy buenas pero esas no importa dejarlas con cero votos porque no saben cómo funciona el sitio y si no vuelven a colaborar como dice el OP no pasa nada porque siempre habrá carne fresca si hacen esto que les digo.

Paz hermanos :)

Comment: Pensé que era una publicación seria, mostrando tu punto de vista y llamando a la discusión sobre los votos.. Recién la estaba leyendo, pero al encontrarme con esta respuesta, parecería que le estás tomando el pelo a quien lee. Encontrarme con esto hace que no quiera seguir leyendo esta publicación, que pierda seriedad tu planteo, y que no pueda ponerme a pensar sobre lo que planteabas en la pregunta. ¿Hay algo que no estoy entendiendo y que te haya hecho publicar semejante respuesta?

Comment: Si hay algo @Mariano . Ayer mismo como pongo EmanueleVe hizo todo lo contrario de lo que planteo pero en ningún momento argumentó nada. Puedes verlo [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/a/54459/19623). Yo paso de esas cosas pero es injusto con x-rw. Además no es el único ya que los comentarios de "mi oposición" tienen votos positivos así que entiendo que nadie piensa como yo. Tambien lo pienso porque esta pregunta no tiene ningún voto positivo así que supongo que nadie apoya mi iniciativa. Para terminar nadie ha entrado en el caso 3, siendo un ejemplo de lo que creo un contenido deseado.

Comment: Por lo anterior @Mariano y a riesgo de tener comentarios como el tuyo me he decidido a caricaturizar de alguna forma esa otra opción. Si no tengo razón cuando he hecho un recopilatorio de los puntos típicos que se deberían evitar pero que se están convirtiendo en legión en este sitio, házmelo saber, pero me ha parecido la mejor forma de iluminar hacia donde vamos si no hacemos caso de la normas, nos volvemos pupulistas, mediocres y no valoramos los verdaderos esfuerzos de calidad. Y que conste que no conozco de nada a leonbloy, pero es que eso ya es un icono de votos dados al azar.

Comment: ¿y como nadie hasta ahora piensa como vos (3 personas o algo así), te enojás y publicás esto? Yo estaba a favor de algunas cosas que planteabas y en contra de otras, pero como te comenté, esta respuesta me desanima un poco a participar (salvo mi -1 a esta respuesta)... No te olvides que lo publicaste un viernes-sábado, cuando menos participación hay y **muy pocos** leen meta en el fin de semana.

Comment: Te has dejado algo importante; que detrás vengo yo y edito la pregunta para que parezca que tenga algún sentido, y luego viene mi amigote con sus 50.000 puntos ya bien ganados y pone su respuesta, que yo voy a votar muy positivamente, por supuesto. De esta manera nos alternaremos, y mientras más de esto haya, más puntos para nosotros. ¿Qué para qué todo eso? Bueno, es el sentido de nuestras vidas fraudulentas amigo, mira a tu alrededor, todos lo hacen.

Comment: Hola @Awes0meM4n. Cualquier propuesta que pretenda obligar al colectivo a obedecer un código de ética va a fracasar, porque los códigos de ética se siguen de manera personalísima y voluntaria. Puedes tener razón en tus planteamientos, pero no puedes obligar a nadie a que los acepte, aunque sea evidente que la otra persona esté equivocada. Te invito a que dediques tus esfuerzos a crear contenido de calidad, a crear comunidad y dejes de lado tratar de cambiar el comportamiento de terceros.

Comment: @toledano yo no quiero que nadie se comporte como digo yo. Llevo sólo unos meses aquí así que no soy ningún jefe ni de lejos. Sólo he leido unas normas y cada vez más veo que no se atienden. También veo el deterioro de la calidad de las publicaciones. Por ejemplo esta semana hubo tres preguntas Java que el código le fallaba porque comparaba un `String` con `==`. Desde que estoy aquí creo que he visto 5 en total. ¿Es casualidad que tres hayan sido en esta semana o es que cada vez hay preguntas más básicas solucionadas por triplicado? ¿Nadie más observa esta tendencia? Sólo quiero arreglarla.

Comment: ¿Y tu respuesta actual abona algo positivo a lo que pretendes hacer? Si quieres arreglarla, hazlo. No tienes porque dedicarle tanto tiempo a exponer tu molestia con respuestas como esta. Es mejor dedicarle el tiempo a lo que si está en tus manos. No puedes, nadie puede, obligar a otro usuario a comentar cuando vota negativo, o a hacer comentarios constructivos cuando proponen para cierre una pregunta. Pretenderlo es perder el tiempo. Puedes proponer y esperar que otras personas hagan algo de lo que propones, pero molestarte porque no siguen tus propuestas, tal vez sea excesivo. Tal vez.

Comment: @toledano yo he hecho una propuesta. El resto puede hacer la suya y la más votada será el consenso. No lo hago para que den la razón. Lo que sí quiero es que si la más votada no encaja con las normas pues que se cambien. Yo no estoy de acuerdo con todas las normas, pero siempre apunto hacia ellas cuando hago un comentario o un voto. Y a esto último me explico por qué lo hago. Por eso sólo pido que se sigan las normas o se cambien porque de lo contrario aquí cada uno hace lo que quiere y es un cachondeo. Esto es lo que deben hacer los moderadores y los veo bastante ausentes.

Comment: ¿Tu propuesta es _No hay que tomarse las normas tan enserio_? Respeto tu opinión, aunque no la comparto.

Comment: No @toledano esta respuesta la hice a todo lo contrario de mi pregunta. La hice porque como nadie mostró ningún apoyo a mi primera propuesta (excepto tú que te campadecías de mi lucha) pues quería ver si esta que es totalmente lo contrario sí que tenía apoyos. Sinceramente creo que no ha servido de nada ni una ni otra.